# Varnish purge on POST or PUT

Tags: http, cache, varnish, couchdb

In my application stack, I'm using CouchDB (in this scenario, to all intents and purposes it's a simple REST server) and I want to put Varnish in front of it to alleviate read load.

I know that whenever my application updates a document through `POST` or `PUT` that the old document is invalidated but, due to the headers that CouchDB puts out, Varnish doesn't realise this and so continues to serve the old version for subsequent `GET` requests.

Basically, I'd like to be able to `purge` the document at a given REST URL when a `POST` or `PUT` method is sent to that same URL.

Can I configure Varnish to achieve this?

I could get my application to send a `PURGE` request after each `POST` or `PUT` but I'd really rather the cache be invisible to the application as, for smaller installations, it might  be run without Varnish in place.

Basically, in `vcl` I'd like to do this:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if ( req.request == "POST" || req.request == "PUT" ) {
            purge;
            return(pass);
    }
}
```

But the `purge;` method isn't available in `vcl_recv`

**Update**

I seem to have achieved something approximating the above by using `ban` instead of `purge` - the immediately subsequent request to the `POST` triggers a `GET` and further `GET` requests are served from the cache, so it seems I misunderstood the semantics.

My subroutine is currently:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if ( req.request == "POST" || req.request == "PUT" ) {
        ban("req.url == " + req.url);
        return(pass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this..

https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/purging.html

basically you are doing a lookup on what you want to pass.. then to the purge in the hit/miss

Comment: That doesn't appear to work - Varnish is still not fetching the object freshly after the POST. I'm running a simple GET - change - POST - GET and the object returned isn't the changed object.

Comment: Turns out I was mis-understanding the difference between purge and ban. A ban line seemed to have the right effect, although it's anyone's guess what will happen under load!

Comment: A `purge` in v2.x is now a `ban` in v3.x -- the terminology change doesn't help (-: At least you have be mindful of it