# Varnish 4 BAN on PUT or POST

Tags: varnish

I need to purge or ban cache that has been modified by an unsafe request. I found a solution that appears to work for varnish 3.0; however I am on varnish 4. It seems this is no longer the correct syntax.

[Varnish purge on POST or PUT](https://serverfault.com/questions/399814/varnish-purge-on-post-or-put)

```
sub vcl_recv {
if ( req.request == "POST" || req.request == "PUT" ) {
    ban("req.url == " + req.url);
    return(pass);
    }
}
```

It's giving me an error

```
Jun 26 17:43:21 test varnishd[2127]: Symbol not found: 'req.request' (expected type BOOL):
Jun 26 17:43:21 test varnishd[2127]: ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 13 Pos 10)
Jun 26 17:43:21 test varnishd[2127]:     if ( req.request == "POST" || req.request == "PUT" ) {
Jun 26 17:43:21 test varnishd[2127]: ---------###########--------------------------------------
Jun 26 17:43:21 test varnishd[2127]: Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
```

What can I do to make varnish purge/ban unsafe requests?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you ever going to have to scale Varnish to >1 instance? Keeping varnish in sync with the backend without a shared cache pool is going to be challenging.

Comment: We use https, so in front of varnish is nginx terminating and proxy to the backend. On each backend server we will have varnish in front of another nginx. So I don't think this is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Varnish 4, req.request became req.method.
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. All appears to be functioning correctly, but will put it through another week of testing before going live on a site.